# How to resolve errors with namespaces and references?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I just added an existing MVC project to VS 2012 that i downloaded from Codeplex. The problem is when i'm trying to build or run the project i get a lot of errors that VS can not find references and namespaces. If i open a new MVC project then i'm not getting this errors and everything runs fine. So it only occurs when i try to open an existing project.

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: show some error which occur at runtime

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 2 18 OdeToFood
C:\Users\Joeri\Desktop\OdeToFood\OdeToFood\Controllers\AccountController.cs 8 7 OdeToFood
Warning 9 Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. OdeToFood

Comment: Warning 13 Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. OdeToFood

Comment: Warning 21 The referenced component 'EntityFramework' could not be found.  OdeToFood

Comment: And so on. In total there are 8 errors and 24 warnings

Comment: install nuget   Package Microsoft.Web.Optimization  see http://forums.asp.net/t/1812274.aspx/1

Comment: I'm still getting errors. This is the link to the project so maybe someone can try to run it without errors. http://odetofoodmvc4.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/ddf7aae7d9ae1723c3c8041bfda0048613027c6e

Comment: I did a manual install from the nuget packages that i was missing in the project. 

After that i still received some errors in the accountcontroller and in the accountmodel. So for now i deleted these files and now is my project working good except the login and register button.

Answer (score 0):

From the VS 2012 menu select Tools->Library Package Manager->Package Manager Settings. A window will appear. Check the checkbox labeled "Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build" under the Package Manager->General heading. Click the OK button to apply the setting.

Next in the Solution Explorer right-click the Solution node and select Enable NuGet Package Restore. Perform a Clean Solution and then a Build Solution. A .nuget folder should be downloaded into your solution and all compile errors related to missing references should be resolved.

This is what worked for me.